# How to convert list to map in terraform?

Tags: terraform

```
    string vals=var.vals // which will contain string in the format below
//"hr:recruitment,department:human,tool:sap,fruit:apple"

    labels={
       hostname=var.hostname
        monitored=var.monitored
        customer=var.cust1
        machine-type=var.machinetype
    }
```

I need to set labels(key,value) pairs for google_compute_instance by combining the above 2 properties to form a map.

So i converted vals to list by this code `split(",",var.vals)`

This gives me a list

```
    tolist([
  "hr:recruitment",
  "department:human",
  "tool:sap",
  "fruit:apple",
])
```

**Expected Output** consisting of only map(string) combining labels and vals

```
labels:
{
            hostname:var.hostname
            monitored:var.monitored
            customer:var.cust1
            machine-type:var.machinetype
            hr:"recruitment",
           department:"human",
          tool:"sap",
          fruit:"apple"
}
```

How to convert this list to a map and combine it with labels?

Comment: You have to provide expected output. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: Are you generating terraform code using any tool? OR are you writing tf scripts yourself? If later is the case, why don't you directly create a map rather than splitting strings.

Comment: They are dynamic inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried below & it seems to be working but it heavily relies on data quality of `vals` string (shouldn't contain duplicate keys). At it's core it relies on [zipmap](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/zipmap) to build the map from keys & values lists.

```
// Having vals as a string variable
variable "vals" {
  description = "The name of availability set"
  type        = string
  default     = "hr:recruitment,department:human,tool:sap,fruit:apple"
}

// hostname, monitored, cust1 & machinetype vars
variable "hostname" {
    type = string
    default = "dummy.net"
}

variable "monitored" {
    type = bool
    default = true
}

variable "cust1" {
    type = string
    default = "xyz"
}

variable "machinetype" {
    type = string
    default = "linux"
}
    
locals {
  // parsing locally to split the vals string to fetch the keys
  keys = [
    for s in split(",", var.vals) : split(":", s)[0]
  ]

  // parsing locally to split the vals string to fetch the values
  values = [
    for s in split(",", var.vals) : split(":", s)[1]
  ]

  //I used labels also as vars
  labels = {
    hostname     = var.hostname
    monitored    = var.monitored
    customer     = var.cust1
    machine-type = var.machinetype
  }
}

// Finally, zipmap to construct map from keys & values & merge with local.labels
output "final_map" {
  value = merge(local.labels, zipmap(local.keys, local.values))
}
```

Finally, the output looks like below ::

```
Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

final_map = {
  "customer" = "xyz"
  "department" = "human"
  "fruit" = "apple"
  "hostname" = "dummy.net"
  "hr" = "recruitment"
  "machine-type" = "linux"
  "monitored" = true
  "tool" = "sap"
}
```

Comment: Thank you,  a minor clarification the variable "vals" can be empty also i.e default="" or default=null, if that is the case, how can this code be modified?

Comment: That can be managed by `count` argument but you haven’t mentioned this before. Ask it as a different question.

Comment: Thank you! i will post a separate thread